# Magento 2: Insert and select operation (without model) in custom module

Tags: magento2, module, database

Please give me any example or link for insert and select process without using model in custom module of Magento 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

**Object Manager :**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$tableName = $resource->getTableName('employee'); //gives table name with prefix

//Select Data from table
$sql = "Select * FROM " . $tableName;
 $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql); // gives associated array, table fields as key in array.

//Insert Data into table
$sql = "Insert Into " . $tableName . " (emp_id, emp_name, emp_code, emp_salary) Values ('','XYZ','ABD20','50000')";
 $connection->query($sql);

//Update Data into table
$sql = "Update " . $tableName . "Set emp_salary = 20000 where emp_id = 12";
$connection->query($sql);
```

**Di method :**

```
<?php
protected $_resourceConnection;
protected $_connection;
public function __construct(
  \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
) {
   $this->_resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
}
public function getCollection()
{   
   $selectData = $this->_resourceConnection->getConnection();
   //Your custom sql query
   $query = "SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE customer_id IN ( 0, 5 ) ORDER BY feed_id DESC ) AS t1 GROUP BY position limit 0,5"; 

   $collection = selectData->fetchAll($query);
   return $collection;
}
public function insertQuery(){
   $insertQuery = $this->_resourceConnection->getConnection();
   //Your custom sql query
   $saveQuery = "SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE customer_id IN ( 0, 5 ) ORDER BY feed_id DESC ) AS t1 GROUP BY position limit 0,5"; 

   $save = $insertQuery->fetchAll($query);
}
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this code's It works Perfectly...